# How can I call a specific return of a function that has multiple returns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The following function has 2 returns (`a, b`) . I would like to print only `a` return and not both.
How can I choose a specific return (e.g. call only `a`)? I would get output: `text 1`

Possibly I wouldn't want to use the class, just a simple function

```
def func():
    a= print("text 1")
    b= print("text 2")
    return a, b

func.a()
```

I get error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'a'`

Comment: `func()[0]` — But in this case the function only returns two `None`s anyway…

Comment: The function does not have “two returns”. It returns *one tuple* with two values.

Comment: Why not return the 2 strings as a tuple, THEN print the one you want, like `print(func()[0])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, your function needs to return two functions, so that you can call the specific one whose effect you want:

```
def func():
    a = lambda: print("text 1")
    b = lambda: print("text 2")
    return a, b

func()[0]()  # text 1
```

Note that this is weird and hard to read —- it is more idiomatic to define an object with methods.